# Servidor HTTP mínimo en Java

Tags: java, http, socket

En el siguiente código se busca implementar un servidor HTTP mínimo en Java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerHTTP {

    private static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Servidor activo en el puerto: " + PORT);
            while (true) {
                new ThreadSocket(server.accept());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class ThreadSocket extends Thread {
        private Socket insocket;

        ThreadSocket(Socket insocket) {
            this.insocket = insocket;
            this.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream is = insocket.getInputStream();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(insocket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                line = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("HTTP-HEADER: " + line);
                line = "";

                // busca post data
                int postDataI = -1;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && (line.length() != 0)) {
                    System.out.println("HTTP-HEADER: " + line);
                    if (line.indexOf("Content-Length:") > -1) {
                        postDataI = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf("Content-Length:") + 16, line.length()));
                    }
                }

                String postData = "";

                // lee el post data
                if (postDataI > 0) {
                    char[] charArray = new char[postDataI];
                    in.read(charArray, 0, postDataI);
                    postData = new String(charArray);
                }
                out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
                out.println("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
                out.println("Server: MINISERVER");
                out.println("");

                // Envía el HTML
                out.println("<H1>Servidor</H1>");
                out.println("<form name=\"input\" action=\"form_submited\" method=\"post\">");
                out.println("Usuario: <input type=\"text\" name=\"user\"><input type=\"submit\"></form>");

                //verificacion
                if(postData.contains("admin")){
                    Bienvenida();
                    out.close();
                    insocket.close();
                }else{
                    out.close();
                    insocket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void Bienvenida() throws IOException{
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(insocket.getOutputStream());
            out.println("<H1>Bienvenido administrador</H1>");
        }
    }
}
```

Una vez que se ejecuta, si se va a cualquier navegador y se accede al localhost:8080 se tendrá la página. Dentro de ella hay una campo para ingresar un "usuario", se debe verificar si el usuario es igual al admin y si es así, se le da la bienvenida. Pensaba que con un simple if bastaría para verificar la condición de entrada, a su vez, mostrar la bienvenida, pero sucede que al ingresar el admin, debajo aparece, de manera muy rápida, un texto que no alcanzo a ver. ¿Es correcto el algoritmo o qué hace falta cambiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregué una función que va a mostrar el formulario, similar a la función que muestra el mensaje de bienvenida. Si la variable `postData` contiene el valor admin entonces llama la función `Bienvenida()`, sino, llama a la función para mostrar el formulario.

Para imprimir la salida usa siempre el mismo `PrintWriter` para que no haya problemas. Si lo vas a usar dentro de una función pásalo como parámetro.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerHTTP {

    private static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Servidor activo en el puerto: " + PORT);
            while (true) {
                new ThreadSocket(server.accept());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class ThreadSocket extends Thread {
        private Socket insocket;

        ThreadSocket(Socket insocket) {
            this.insocket = insocket;
            this.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream is = insocket.getInputStream();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(insocket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                line = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("HTTP-HEADER: " + line);
                line = "";

                // busca post data
                int postDataI = -1;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && (line.length() != 0)) {
                    System.out.println("HTTP-HEADER: " + line);
                    if (line.indexOf("Content-Length:") > -1) {
                        postDataI = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf("Content-Length:") + 16, line.length()));
                    }
                }

                String postData = "";

                // lee el post data
                if (postDataI > 0) {
                    char[] charArray = new char[postDataI];
                    in.read(charArray, 0, postDataI);
                    postData = new String(charArray);
                }

                out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
                out.println("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
                out.println("Server: MINISERVER");
                out.println("");



                //verificacion
                if(postData.contains("admin")){
                    Bienvenida(out);
                    out.close();
                    insocket.close();
                }else{

                    EnviarFormulario(out);

                    out.close();
                    insocket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void EnviarFormulario(PrintWriter out){
            // Envía el HTML
                out.println("<H1>Servidor</H1>");
                out.println("<form name=\"input\" action=\"form_submited\" method=\"post\">");
                out.println("Usuario: <input type=\"text\" name=\"user\"><input type=\"submit\"></form>");
        }
        public void Bienvenida(PrintWriter out) throws IOException{

            out.println("<H1>Bienvenido administrador</H1>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda :) Esto resolvió el problema